# Doc Stubborn and the search for Pdf User Space and Device Space Knowledge

Tags: c#, pdf

After putting togheter enough code to parse a pdf file, i'm actually struck on how to handle the decoded stream content, describing how to "draw" the actual page content. Apart from the concepts of operators "drawing this or that, or move from here to there", which are mostly self-explanatory, i can't realize the idea of user space or device space. I simply do not understand what they are, and how should i represent them in code. Can anyone point me to a good source of technical information on the subject (maybe a book RATHER than the sea of words known as "PDF Specs")? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly out-of-the box suggestion, but you should try reading the Apple Quartz 2D documentation. Obviously, you are not on OS X (since you have tagged c#), but I make this suggestion because the Quartz 2D drawing model is almost the same as the PDF drawing model. In fact, rendering a PDF content stream on OS X (and iOS) is very easy because, corresponding to every PDF operator is the equivalent Quartz call (using a framework call Core Graphics).

Start with [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH202-TPXREF101).

(The reason for this similarity is because the initial Mac OS/NextStep drawing model was based on something called Display Postscript.)

As for user space and device space - they are pretty intuitive. The device space is just the coordinate system for the device: where the origin is, and which direction the axes go. So on OS X, for example, a screen's origin is at the top left hand corner of the screen, whereas PDF Page Space has an origin (usually) on the bottom left hand corner of the page. This means that EVERY thing you draw has to be transformed appropriately, which seems pretty cumbersome, except that this so-called CTM can be applied once (in the OS X case it involves a scale transform to flip the page, and a translate to slide it down). In the Quartz case, once you have applied these two transforms to the drawing context, you can forget about the problem. I imagine that the Windows API you are using has a very similar solution.

It would be helpful to if you read the Wikipedia entry on Affine Transforms.

Comment: Sorry for being so late (real life issues) and thank you for your aswer: it  helped me pointing in the right direction. I managed to write some graphics and text on a Canvas (despite some problems in interpreting the text and text line matrix, among other things).
As you say, by setting the LayoutTransform of Canvas to ctm values, gave me a visually consistent result, so it seems the right way to go.
The real problem remains the lack of information about what to expect in some of the most difficult tasks (e.g. pdf font objects).
Anyway, thanks again for your answer. I'll figure out something!

Comment: I know you are not crazy about the PDF Spec, and  it does have its problems, but I highly recommend you read section 5.3 Text Objects - I followed it closely to make sure that I got the glyph positioning exactly right. Fonts is an entire other can of worms, and your options there are going to be platform dependent. Good luck.